# Facebook image post works despite "plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've seen a few Q&As here about this error message, but the result for those was that the image or the text did not appear. I'm getting this error message when using the Social framework, but everything seems to post just fine.

```
-(void)postToFB
{if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:fbDesc];
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screengrab);
    UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [mySLComposerSheet addImage:  pngImage];
    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"User cancelled FB posting");
                break;

            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"User continued with FB posting");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

The **screengrab** variable is exactly that -- a UIImage of the screen taken previous to this code being executed. The **fbdesc** variable is a NSString of text entered previously. I'm signed in as myself for Facebook.

After I run this app and press the button that captures the screen and starts this code, the confirmation message "User continued with FB posting" appears, then the error message "plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated". I check my Facebook page and the screen grab image is there, along with the text. I go to another computer and check my Facebook page -- image and text are there.

So, this is more a question about what to do about that error message.  Nothing? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this question for the last week, I think the answer seems to be that the error message is the result of a "premature termination" of the Facebook/Apple connection (said termination being considered premature on the Apple end) and that the Facebook posting is not affected.  From [this Apple Developers forum link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/57861#57861), it appears the error message is an irrelevant response after the fact.